# VS Code Intellisense Displays Nonsense

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

VS Code has been pointlessly displaying a "j" option in Intellisense for so long that I now instinctively press "escape" in certain situations. It seems to happen primarily while in Python language mode.

[image: Intellisense displaying a "j" option for no reason.]

Comment: Have you tried disabling all extensions you have installed?

Comment: It was the django-intellisense extension. Thank you, kind stranger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Have you tried disabling all extensions you have installed?" – HolyBlackCat